# How do I add custom properties to xcconfig file when building iOS flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

So I merged our native iOS app and our newer version which uses Flutter. The app has a switch to toggle between the native UI and the Flutter UI. The native code had separate xcconfig files for different environments like `Staging.xcconfig`.

When building the iOS app with Flutter it generates its own xcconfig files on every build. One is `Generated.xcconfig` and the other is something like `Pod-Runner.debug.xcconfig`. How do I add properties from the native `Staging.xcconfig` to these generated files?

As far as possible I don't want to change the structure and working of the native app.

I feel like there's a very simple solution to this but I don't know much about it as I am quite new to iOS.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to add properties to the generated files? If there are environment variables in your custom xcconfig files why not just use those directly (or using copies)?

Comment: hey @shim thanks for the edit. Also I can't use the custom files because Flutter seems to have both files generated with the latest Flutter version. One is `Generated.xcconfig` and the other is something like `Pod-Runner.debug.xcconfig` and both of them hold data required to build the app and some paths and stuff. If I try replacing either with the custom xcconfig files the build fails.

Comment: But why can't you just leave the generated xcconfig files alone? You can use as many xcconfig files as you want.

Comment: I can? how do I do that? I added an image above. The one with the blue icon and "App" written next to it has the `Generated.xcconfig` set to it. And the one with the red icon and "App" writted next to it has `Pod-Runner.debug.xcconfig` set to it.

Comment: Once again new to iOS so I'm not sure how to do a lot of things that might be simple.

Comment: It's hard to really explain without knowing the structure of your project and how you fit these two pieces together. Plus someone with more specific knowledge of Flutter should probably answer.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors — seems similar to how you'd do it in native iOS, and no need to touch generated files…

Comment: This is exactly how I do it. But There are 2 Generated files by Flutter and both of them are used for any flavor created in xcode. I don't think Flutter gave much thought to the possibility of combining native apps with a Flutter app. As an iOS developer do you know how to add a third xcconfig file in xcode? Like in the image I posted above the default structure in xcode allows only 2 to be added to any flavor.